# Is there any way to negate if statement but except 'and' operator inside it in just single line else statement?

Tags: python, if-statement, logic

As I know so far, we can use not operator and rewrite if statement with not operator (or reverse all the signs) ! But since my code have more than 10 conditions in one if statement with many and operators, this seem makes my code duplicate and hard to read. As Example below:

```
If a>b and A>B and R<w<a<Q and ....
# Else case is just reverse like this
Elif a<b and A<B and R>w>a>Q and ... # Thanks for @bOb for correct the syntax of this example
# I can not use just single Else without rewrite all condition (code will know a<b or A<B and ...)
```

Anyone have any ideas to clean this code? Or just keep the safe way is rewrite everything> Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can't you do something like this `check =a>b and A>B and R<w<a<Q` and then use `if check` & `if not check`?

Comment: @moys It doesn't work correctly, since we have 1000 rows, if it True then there are 4-5 rows for this case. But when it False, all the rest of rows is in the other case which is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all conditions are strict inequalities (`<` or `>`) you could do

```
pairs = [(a, b), (A, B), (Q, a), (a, w), (w, R), ...]
if all(x > y for (x, y) in pairs):
  ...
elif all(x < y for (x, y) in pairs):
  ...
```

> [`all`: Return True if all elements of the iterable are true (or if the iterable is empty)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all)

If there are other possibilities, you'll need to modify that a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Your Boolean logic is flawed.

The opposite of (A and B and C) is (!A or !B or !C) -- if you negate the conditions, you need to switch operators.

Your syntax is flawed. "ELSE" does need or allow a condition; its just the word "ELSE"

"ELSE IF" is a whole different animal; that keyword in Python is ELIF and your condition should be something other than the diametric opposite of the condition in the IF.

Something like this:

```
if a>b and A>B and R<w<a<Q:
   ... code will run when all conditions are true
elif a<b:
   ... code will run when first initial condition failed
else:
   ... code will run when A<B or !(R<w<a<Q)
```

2) The condition **R<w<a<Q** is invalid in most computer languages and would need to be a series of ANDed single inequality conditions, ie (R<w && w<a && a<Q)

Or you could always nest

```
if a>b :
   if A>B :
      if R<w and w<a and a<Q :
         # your "everything's true" code
      else :
         # your not R<a<w<Q code
   else :
      # your A<B code
else :
   # your a>b code
```

**Caveat:** I'm a C/C++/C# programmer, Python is not my strong point.

Comment: Thanks for your rely, I admit that I'm negligent when using wrong syntax example and I have edit again - many thanks again. But the point I want to ask is the way to cut down more duplicate lines of condition code as possible since it's pattern just need to reverse all the signs except 'and' operators.

Comment: Not sure I follow the question then ... there's no need to have a reverse condition on the else, the keyword does that for you.  If you need to handle different "misses" of the original condition differently, then you will need to specify those conditions (like in my first example, the "elif a<b" clause does repeat the a>b condition reversed) -- I'm not aware of any way around that need.

Comment: 1. In Python, `R<w<a<Q` works. 2. The whole point is that `a<b and A<B and R>w>a>Q and ...` is not the opposite of `a>b and A>B and R<w<a<Q and ...` so it's a reasonable condition for `elif`.

Comment: 1) re R<w<a<Q ... kewl.  :-) First computer language I've seen that accepts it.
2) You're right.  :-) it is a distinct condition, I misunderstood thinking you were trying to explicitly specify an opposite else condition.